# What is the Mongraal Special?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I've hear this term thrown around, and understand parts of it, but I'm not entirely clear on what exactly this move is, from beginning to end.

I believe the finish, from an adjacent block, is:

1. Ramp over your opponent
2. Back-edit one side of the ramp. This both reverses the ramp, and splits it in half. The half-split isn't really needed; it's for speed: this edit is faster than rotating the ramp 180 degrees.
3. Hit your shot--quickly :)

Is this all there is to it? Is there more, in the setup?

Answer (score -1):

The Mongraal technique is basicaly what you said.
The important things are:

-Put a wall and a stair behind it at the same time... [ it's better to box completely your opponent]

{try to watch this}

-A complete reverse of stairs is not the best because your opponent can hide behind it... it's better to do a back/ front one side edit